# How can I specify different output directories for different SCSS files?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I'm using VS2013 with Web Essentials support for SCSS.

I have a single directory '/Resources/SCSS' for SCSS files.

Some need to Export to '/Resources/Style', others need to go to 'AppThemes/[ThemeName]'. Can I specify the directory I want in the SCSS file?

Web Essentials supplies a single Custom Output Directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I may provide you simple alternate solution for the same.

Just create a simple .scss file there in 'AppThemes/[ThemeName]' say 'site2.scss'

and import your required .scss files in 'site2.sccs'. It will create a css file for you.